# Workflow foundation 4.5 custom database for tracking

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am planning to use Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5.
I need to track information in a custom database.
Lists will be shown in a user interface (my tasks, all tasks).
What is the best way to have a generic system by which I don't need to add custom activities to a workflow.

- workflow created
- workflow ended
- workflow terminated
- receive activity started (log custom record in a table)
- receive activity completed
  --> bookmark events?? I also need to correlate an activity instance id with the record in the database.
  ...

Do I use a tracking participant for this or can I tap into the events of the workflow service host??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add custom activities to your workflow. You can implement SQL tracking participant. Here is a sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622983.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Tracking participant is the solution to choose here... it is really flexible.  You can get the status of the workflow instance with the WorkflowInstanceRecord and the activity status with the ActivityStateRecord. Both records have the instanceId to correlate them.

Also you can track custom tracking in your code activities with the CustomTrackingRecord.

We are using it for long time and the performance is quite good.

I hope it helps.